# change an image using ajax request in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I want to use `$.ajax` to get any picture from a URL and show it on the page.
It should happen when button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({url: "index.html", success: function(result){
         $("#image").attr("src","test.png");
      }});
   });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<button type = "button">Click Me</button>
<div>
   <img id = "image" src = ""/>
</div>
```

Edit: 
The errors is, [image]

Comment: You are not using `result` anywhere..I guess you forgot to mention what is not working.....

Comment: You code seems fine. What is the actual problem?

Comment: What is the question or problem? What is being sent in ajax response?

Comment: @GokulShinde see the edit

Comment: Yes, it seems you are trying to call ajax on another domain url and that is unfortunately not supported by ajax.

Comment: What are the contents of `index.html` ? What is the full path to the image file ?

Comment: You are calling this from opening a file directly and browsers won't allow ajax on `file://` protocol. Need to install a localhost server on your computer to use ajax. Lots of easy ways to set it up.

Comment: Try to google the console error message. You'll get 10s of similar SO questions.

Comment: @guest271314 see the HTML code in the question

Comment: @RayonDabre See the edit. Image not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a server and serve your file over the http protocol

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. But still I need to use a localserver to run this without the console error mentioned in edit.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
            $("button").click(function(){
                var url = 'test.png';
                $.ajax({ 
                    url : url, 
                    cache: true,
                    processData : false,
                }).always(function(){
                    $("#image").attr("src", url);
                }); 
            });
        });
```

Comment: At chrome / chromium can set `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag at launch to use `$.ajax()` without a utilizing a local webserver